# How to parallelize a program with a shared data structure without locking it?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing

I have a sequential program, its aim is to construct a binary-tree. It starts at the root, and create the left child, at the same time, it adds the right child into a taskList. Then it continues on the left child, and creates the left child's left child and adds the right child into the taskList. After finishing one branch, it would get a task from the taskList and continue.

The program is like:

```
while !tasklist.is_empty() {
    fn explore(node: Node, &mut tasklist) {
        create left_child;
        create right_child;
        add_task(right_child, tasklist);
        explore(left_child, tasklist);
    }
}
```

Now I want to parallelize it. Assume we have 4 threads, T2, T3, T4 should sleep for a while to wait T1 adds tasks to the tasklist. Then, 4 threads would get tasks from the tasklist, and also add tasks from the tasklist. But, there would be no speedup if I add a lock on the tasklist. So, I wonder if there is a non-blocking stack that could shared between threads safely.

```
 // Create a work-stealing deque to hold tasks
 let mut tasklist = Arc::new(Worker::<Arc<Node>>::new_lifo());
 tasklist.push(root);

 // Create a stealer for each thread
 let mut stealers = Vec::new();
 for _ in 0..4 {
     let stealer = tasklist.stealer();
     stealers.push(stealer)
 }
 // Spawn threads to do the work
 let mut handles = Vec::new();
 for i in 0..4 {
     let stealer = stealers[i].clone();
     let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
         if i != 0 {
             thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(2));
         }
         while true {
             let task = match stealer.steal() {
                 Steal::Success(task) => task,
                 Steal::Empty => break,
                 Steal::Retry => continue,
             };
             let result: bool = explore(task.clone(), &mut tasklist);
             if result {
                 break;
             }
         }
     });
     handles.push(handle)
 }
 for handle in handles {
     handle.join().unwrap();
 }
```

What I tried is to use the crossbem::deque, but the compiler says

```
error[E0277]: `Cell<deque::deque::Buffer<Arc<lib::Node>>>` cannot be shared between threads safely                                
   --> src\main.rs:43:36
    |
43  |           let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    |  ______________________-------------_^
    | |                      |
    | |                      required by a bound introduced by this call
44  | |             if i != 0 {
45  | |                 thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(2));
46  | |             }
...   |
58  | |             }
59  | |         });
    | |_________^ `Cell<deque::deque::Buffer<Arc<lib::Node>>>` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: within `Worker<Arc<lib::Node>>`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Cell<deque::deque::Buffer<Arc<lib::Node>>>`  
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Worker<Arc<lib::Node>>`
    = note: required for `Arc<Worker<Arc<lib::Node>>>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it's used within this closure
   --> src\main.rs:43:36
    |
43  |         let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                                    ^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `std::thread::spawn`
   --> C:\Users\FZQ\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:662:8      
    |
662 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `std::thread::spawn`
```

An example of the sequential version:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Node {
    variable: i32,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(
        variable: i32
    ) -> Self {
        Node {
            variable,
        }
    }
}

pub fn explore(node: Arc<Node>, tasklist: &mut Vec<Arc<Node>>) -> bool {
    println!("tasklist len = {}", tasklist.len());
    if node.variable == 0 {
        let left_child = Arc::new(Node {
            variable: 1,
        });
        let right_child = Arc::new(Node {
            variable: 1,
        });
        tasklist.push(right_child);
        return explore(left_child, tasklist);
    } else if node.variable == 1 {
        let left_child = Arc::new(Node {
            variable: 2,
        });
        let right_child = Arc::new(Node {
            variable: 2,
        });
        tasklist.push(right_child);
        return explore(left_child, tasklist);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let root = Arc::new(Node::new(
        0,
    ));
    let mut tasklist: Vec<Arc<Node>> = Vec::new();
    tasklist.push(root);
    while !tasklist.is_empty() {
        let node = tasklist.pop().unwrap();
        let result = explore(node, &mut tasklist);
        if result {
            println!("get bottom");
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to use multi threads to get node from the tasklist and explore, also, they need to add new child nodes into the tasklist.
The code is also available on the Rust [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe6ad9116984572d5daaae367b503e9e).

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: There is not much meaning to a stack being used in the parallel implementation, since the threading will anyway cause the visit to not be in order. Does it matter to you, or you can use a queue?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You are right. I don't need to use a stack. The main point is to make multi threads operate on one data structure without a lock. I create an example of the sequential version on the playground. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe6ad9116984572d5daaae367b503e9e   What I want is to use multi threads to get node from the tasklist and explore, also, they need to add new child nodes into the tasklist

Comment: Even your "complete" example isn't really.  But I'd think of it from a data structure problem, not a Rust problem: How do you plan to keep a reference/pointer/something to the node that needs to be updated in a different thread?  How do you lock access to such cross-thread such that you don't lock the entire data structure, but just enough to work with?  Similar for your queue: you don't need non-locking, but be able to lock and extract what you need, then unlock while you're working.  Solve those problems, and you'll have a solution.  It'll probably involve `Arc<Mutex<Node>>` at some point.